# How to define a C# class model for these dataobjects

Tags: c#, class, model, datamodel

How can I define classes with properties where the following code would compile and be valid?

```
AtomEntry newPost = new AtomEntry();
newPost.Title.Text = "Marriage!";
newPost.Content = new AtomContent();
newPost.Content.Content = "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>" +
  "<p>Mr. Darcy has <em>proposed marriage</em> to me!</p>" +
  "<p>He is the last man on earth I would ever desire to marry.</p>" +
  "<p>Whatever shall I do?</p>" +
  "</div>";
newPost.Content.Type = "xhtml";
```

Comment: It's not clear to me. Isn't this C# class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```cs
public class AtomEntry 
{ 
    public AtomContent Content { get; set; } 
    public Title Title { get; set; } 
}

public class AtomContent 
{ 
    public string Content { get; set; } 
    public string Type { get; set; } 
}

public class Title 
{ 
    public string Text { get; set; } 
}
```